# Dynamically create fallback delegate at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection, expression, ironpython

I'm trying to setup C# code to automatically create dummy or fallback delegates for methods that get called by an IronPython script and that are not explicitly implemtented, yet.

Say there's a script that calls the non-static C# class method "MoveTo" which isn't implemented in the corresponding class yet. Usually, in case it exists, it is added to the script's scope by creating a corresponding delegate instance that is given to the scope by a call to "SetVariable" with the name of the Method and the delegate instance. That works fine for methods that already are implemented.

In case the method is not yet implemented the call shall not fail but instead be redirected to a dummy method that gracefully handles the call and *pretends* successful execution (which is to be considered uncritical in my specific case).

The problem is: the methods invoked by the IronPython script have a wide range of signatures (actually they can have any possible kind of signature). Therefore I'd like to dynamically create a fallback delegate that gets the same signature of the called method and hence "catches" every call to not yet implemented methods.

Do you guys have any idea on how I can achieve this goal?

Comment: Could you further clarify your questions and add some samples? You say that you call "non-static C# class methods" by adding them via name/delegate via SetVariable. Does that mean that in your python script they look like global/static/non-member functions instead of member call on CLR object instances (while still being implicitly bound to a non-exposed CLR object)? None of the methods is returning anything?

Comment: So basically you wish to create a method with specific signature at runtime? Have you looked on SO for dynamic creation of lambda expressions?

Comment: @SimonOpelt: that's correct. In IronPython they look like global functions. The object they belong to is kind of a singleton, there is only one instance of this class in the whole application. The object represents a piece of hardware, a robot to be more precise. IronPython is used to script the behaviour of the robot. The exposed methods control the different abilities of the robot like driving, turning, moving its arms, things like that.

Comment: @JJ15k I somehow have, actually. But I basically haven't found anything yet that helped me come close to what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a catch-all method that takes any number/type of args:

```
object Fallback([ParamDictionary]IDictionary<object, object> kwargs, params object[] args) {
  return null; // or whatever
}
```

(Sadly, this is backwards from the normal Python way of writing a similar function: `def foo(*args, **kwargs):`.)

If you don't use keywords args, you can drop that and just use `params`:

```
object Fallback(params object[] args) {
  return null; // or whatever
}
```

Then use `.SetVariable("whatever", Fallback)` to make it the fallback method.

Comment: I'm able to create one by generating suitable Python code at runtime and execute that in the corresponding scope. Unfortunately, your method did not work as .SetVariable expects a Delegate object and strangely throws an error when given a method group. Creating the delegate with Delegate.CreateDelegate(...) doesn't work either because the resulting delegate does not fit the invoked Python function. Well, anyway, it works the way I do it now. It's quick'n'dirty but I consider it acceptable. Thanks anyway!